# Update Nested state in react

Tags: reactjs, object, state

Hello guys I'm trying to update the state of a nested object in react, I'm currently doing this:

```
handleChange({target: {id, value}}, type) {
    this.setState(
        state => ({
            dwelling: (Object.assign(state.dwelling, {[id]: {[type]: value}}))
        })
    );
}
```

it comes from a formgroup:

```
<FormGroup controlId="spaces">
    <ControlLabel>Dormitorios</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl
        componentClass="select"
        value={dwelling.spaces.dorms}
        placeholder="Seleccione"
        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'dorms')}
    >
```

The problem is when I update the state of the sub object `dwelling.spaces.dorms` is created but when I try to place another property it replaces the old one instead of getting added:

Before `Dwelling`:

```
{
   address: "",
   currency: "",
   price: 0,
   publicationType: "",
   spaces: {
     closets: "",
     dorms: "",
     pools: ""
   },
   subtype: "",
   type: ""
}
```

After onChange for `dwelling.spaces.dorms`

```
{
   address: "",
   currency: "",
   price: 0,
   publicationType: "",
   spaces: {
     dorms: "3",
   },
   subtype: "",
   type: ""
}
```

After onChange for `dwelling.spaces.closets`

```
{
   address: "",
   currency: "",
   price: 0,
   publicationType: "",
   spaces: {
     closets: "3",
   },
   subtype: "",
   type: ""
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example uses ES6 spread operator to keep your old properties which is the equivalent of Object.assign.

So what was happening is you're not keeping your nested value.

```
this.setState({
  dwelling: {
    ...this.state.dwelling,
    [id]: { 
      ...this.state.dwelling[id],
      [type]: value
    }  
  }
});
```

In your example you overwrote your value with a new object. Notice the bolded text below.

> dwelling: (Object.assign(state.dwelling, **{[id]: {[type]: value}**}))

In the bolded text it specifically set a new object into state.dwelling without keeping the old values. So what we did is that we used the ES6 spread operator to help merge your old values with the new value

```
{ 
  ...this.state.dwelling[id],
  [type]: value
}
```

Comment: I worked perfect i added `state =>` to keep it functional. what was  going on on the last one?

Comment: What happened is you needed to also use Object.assign in your nested value `Object.assign(state.dwelling, {[id]: Object.assign(state.dwelling[id], {[type]: value}) })`

Comment: You were overwriting your [id] with a new value and your new value never got the old props which is why you needed to use either the spread or the Object.assign in the nested value

Comment: can you explain what your code done to explicit your solution please

Comment: thanks for the precision @KennethTruong, if I understand well, on the first sequence in your first example, in setState, `dwelling: {
    ...this.state.dwelling,
    [id]` is equivalent to `this.state.dwelling.id`

Comment: O no! If you read up on ES6 spread operator `...this.state.dwelling` will copy over the whole object for you. While any properties behind it will be merged in. So `{...this.state.dwelling }` is the same as dwelling. (Except it creates a new object)

Answer (score 2):

I keep my form state in a complex object and to simplify my code I use this helper function in my "handleChange" function referenced by TextField, Select, etc..

```
export function updateObject(obj, keys, value) {
  let key = keys.shift();
  if (keys.length > 0) {
    let tmp = updateObject(obj[key], keys, value);
    return {...obj, [key]: tmp};
  } else {
    return {...obj, [key]: value};
  }
}
```

React-redux/Material-UI example

```
let [formState, changeFormState] = useState({});

function handleChange(event) {
  changeFormState(updateObject(formState, event.target.name.split('.'), 
event.target.value));
}

<TextField className={classes.textfield} name='foo.bar' value= 
formstate.foo.bar || ''} onChange={handleChange} />
```